# Normalising JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, redux

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
  },
  "title": "My awesome blog post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "324",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is JSON for an article

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "articles": { 
      "123": { 
        id: "123",
        author: "1",
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [ "324" ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" }
    }
  }
}
```

Im currently looking through redux tutorials, they give a helper which normalise JSON data, does anyone know what type of normalisation this is?

Comment: what? 10 more to go...

Comment: I dont understand your comment

Comment: you can build custom ```json``` file and set in key/value in the result message.